# How do I use autoconf with Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, autoconf

**Environment**
Windows 7
Cygwin 2.0.2(0.287/5/3)

I have installed autoconf and I have tried...

```
$ autoconf-2.69
autom4te-2.69: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4
```

and

```
$ autoconf-2.13
Autoconf requires GNU m4 1.1 or later
```

and

```
$ autoconf
autom4te-2.69: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4
```

I tried...

```
$ m4 --version
```

per the man but it doesn't print anything

```
 --version
          output version information and exit
```

This is all super strange and I have confirmed it is installed...

```
$ apt-cyg install m4
Package m4 is already installed, skipping
```

How do I get autoconf to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ m4 --version
```

producing no output is a symptom of missing dll`s or mismatch in their version
due to a failed upgrade. I bet you upgraded cygwin with a process still running.

running `strace m4 --version` will likely confirm the version mismatch and will advise of a missing symbol.

Controlling m4 dependencies we have

```
$ cygcheck m4
Found: D:\cygwin64\bin\m4.exe
D:\cygwin64\bin\m4.exe
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygsigsegv-2.dll
```

Of course you have a `cygwin1.dll` but it could be a wrong version.
For the other dependency

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/cygsigsegv-2.dll
libsigsegv2-2.10-2
```

So you should re-install the packages: `cygwin` and `libsigsegv2`

Comment: Humm can't do a apt-cyg remove cygwin so I am not sure how I would do that.

Comment: Do I need to change the mirror to match the installed Cygwin version?

Comment: BTW the m4 error is "The procedure entry point __locale_ctype_ptr could not be located in the dynamic link library cygwin1.dll"

Comment: @JGleason use cygwin setup to reinstall the two packages

Comment: No an option I don't have permissions to reinstall oh well

Comment: Maybe I can generate a configure file on a VM where I have full control and copy it

Comment: you will have problem with other programs later as your cygwin1.dll is not the latest.